# How to check in sub-chart that parent's chart configmap has been changed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'am trying to use sha256sum to detect changes in ConfigMap and trigger pod restart.
ConfigMap is deployed by the parent chart in cluster. All works fine in the env section but there is a problem with second checksum. I did not understand what the right path for should look like.

**deployment.yaml of sub chart:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test-project.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test-project.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "test-project.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test-project.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test-project.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
        checksum/config1: {{ include (print $.Files.Get "configmaps/myproduct.yaml") . | sha256sum }} //error line
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            {{- if not .Values.security.useSSLConnection }}
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.springboot.server.port | default 8080 }}
              protocol: TCP
            {{- else }}
            - name: https
              containerPort: {{ .Values.springboot.server.port | default 8080 }}
              protocol: TCP
            {{- end }}
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: {{ .Values.readiness.path | default "/actuator/ready" }}
              port: {{ .Values.springboot.actuator.port | default "http" }}
              scheme: HTTP{{ if $.Values.security.useSSLConnection }}S{{ end }}
            initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.readiness.initialDelaySeconds | default 10 }}
            periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readiness.periodSeconds | default 10 }}
            timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.readiness.timeoutSeconds | default 1 }}
            successThreshold: {{ .Values.readiness.successThreshold | default 1 }}
            failureThreshold: {{ .Values.readiness.failureThreshold | default 3 }}
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: {{ .Values.liveness.path | default "/actuator/alive" }}
              port: {{ .Values.springboot.actuator.port | default "http" }}
              scheme: HTTP{{ if $.Values.security.useSSLConnection }}S{{ end }}
            initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.liveness.initialDelaySeconds | default 300 }}
            periodSeconds: {{ .Values.liveness.periodSeconds | default 10 }}
            timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.liveness.timeoutSeconds | default 1 }}
            successThreshold: {{ .Values.liveness.successThreshold | default 1 }}
            failureThreshold: {{ .Values.liveness.failureThreshold | default 3 }}
          env:
            - name: MY_PRODJECT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: my-product
                  key: prj-version
            - name: ACTUATOR_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.springboot.actuator.port }}"
            - name: USE_SSL
              value: "{{ .Values.security.useSSLConnection }}"
            - name: CRL_ENABLED
              value: "{{ .Values.security.CRLEnabled }}"
```

**ConfigMap myproduct.yaml from parent chart:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-product
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  prj-version: "0.3"
```